# strncpy only copies part of string

Tags: c, string, strncpy

Supposed I have structures like this

```
typedef struct _student {
    int studentID;
    char name[30];
    char class[10];
    char department[10];
} Student;
```

and the following function creates new variables of type Student:

```
Student *new_student(int id, char *name, char *class, char *dept) {
    Student *s = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student *));

    s->studentID = id;
    strncpy(s->name, name, sizeof(s->name) - 1);
    s->name[sizeof(s->name) - 1] = '\0';
    strncpy(s->class, class, sizeof(s->class) - 1);
    s->class[sizeof(s->class) - 1] = '\0';
    strncpy(s->department, dept, sizeof(s->department) - 1);
    s->department[sizeof(s->department) - 1] = '\0';
    return s;
}

void display_student(Student *s) {
    printf("Student: %d | %s | %s | %s\n", s->studentID, s->name, s->class, s->department);
}
```

To test my code, I just write something simple in my main()

```
int main() {

    Student *s1 = new_student(20111201, "Lurther King Anders Something", "ICT-56", "SoICT");
    Student *s2 = new_student(20111202, "Harry Potter", "ICT-56", "SoICT");
    Student *s3 = new_student(20111203, "Hermione Granger", "ICT-56", "SoICT");
    Student *s4 = new_student(20111204, "Ron Weasley", "ICT-56", "SoICT");
    display_student(s1);
    display_student(s2);
    display_student(s3);
    display_student(s4);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the results is unexpected and weird to me:

[image: Erro]

Can someone please explain for me why the weird result is! I think I did things in a correct manner, I've applied safe use of strncpy, but I dont' understand the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
 ... malloc(sizeof(Student *));
```

allocates

```
sizeof(Student *)
```

bytes. Which typically is 4 or 8 as `Student *` is a pointer type.

You propably want

```
     ... malloc(sizeof(Student));
```

ov even better:

```
Student * s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

or even without the useless parenthesis:

```
Student * s = malloc(sizeof *s); /* sizeof is an operator, not a function. */
```

Read `malloc(sizeof *s)` as: "*Allocate as much bytes as what `s`  is pointing to.*"

Comment: Oh, I see. thank you very much. I didn't see that simple thing. I will accept your answer right now :D

Answer (score 2):

```
Student *s = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student *));
```

That line is wrong. You allocate memory you want to use for a `Student`, but only ask for enough for a `Student*`.

You can make such an error much less likely by passing an expression instead of a type to `sizeof`.
Also, [in C you don't cast on assigning from a `void*` to an other data-pointer-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845):

```
Student *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

As a suggestion, consider using [`strlcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html), if neccessary defining it yourself.
Unless, of course, you rely on zeroing the rest of the buffer, like because you write them directly to a file.
`strncpy` is nearly always wrong, though you seem to have adroitely avoided all the pitfalls (with the possible exception of performance).

Comment: I've not heard about strlcpy (I'm starting out with C). Thank you for your suggestion, I'm gonna find more about that

Comment: `strlcpy()` is not part of the C Standard. @DucCuong It is an extension on some platforms.

Answer (score -1):

Ok first of all:
malloc(sizeof(Student*)) you got just size of pointers that is 4 bytes so you didn't get enough memory for your struct. I'm wondering how it is actually work, but whatever. So to get size of your struct use following example:

> Student *s = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));

Second you allocated new paice of data in heap, after you try to perform:

> strncpy(s->name, name, sizeof(s->name) - 1);

Here your *s->name* has some garbage in the memory because you didn't assigned any data to this memory, you should use length of data that is in argument of function

```
 Student *new_student(int id, char *name, char *classSt, char *dept) 
{
    Student *s = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));

    s->studentID = id;

    strncpy(s->name, name, strlen(name) + 1);
    strncpy(s->classSt, classSt, strlen(classSt) + 1);
    strncpy(s->department, dept, strlen(dept) + 1);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: "*you should use length of data*" This is very dangerous, as the source might be longer then the destination and with this the `strncpy()` would write behind the destination. Also `sizeof(s->name)` as per the OP's code will always be `30` independently wether `s->name` had been initilaised or not. -1

Comment: NO, you built a buffer overflow trap. You give the size of the destination buffer, not the length of the input.